# In snowflake Can we use aggregate functions in Non-materialized Views? like sum(),max() etc

Tags: function, view, aggregate, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Can we use aggregate functions like sum(), max() in snowflake  Non-materialized Views?

Answer (score 0):

short answer: Yes

longer:
A view is just a projection of a table/s, and thus aggregating from it is the same as working with the underlying tables. The only difference a materialized View provides is acknowledgement the tables have a large amount of data in them, and it not "performant" to read from them all the time, or the transformation that the materialized view is doing is consistent thus some computation can be saved.

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate functions are supported in *Standard Views*, which in general have very few limitations: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/views-introduction.html#limitations-on-views

On the contrary, many aggregate functions are **Not** supported in *Materialized Views* - although either SUM and MAX are supported instead. Nevertheless, aggregate functions that are allowed in *Materialized Views* still have some restrictions: See '[Limitations on Creating Materialized Views](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/views-materialized.html#limitations-on-creating-materialized-views)'